# Is pre-fetching assets in Service Workers really the best idea?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

All examples of offline web apps using Service Workers, I have seen, include following pattern to pre-fetch their assets on installation:

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(caches.open('assets').then(function(cache) {
      return cache.addAll([
        '/',
        '/static/all.css',
        '/static/script.js',
        ...
      ])
    }));
});
```

However, I experienced following issues with this approach:

1. On first load, the assets are fetched twice, once during initial page load (before the Service Worker is active), and once again the Service Worker gets installed.
2. Is it possible that responses pre-fetched during installation get automatically removed from the cache (when the website hasn't been visited in a while or running low on storage)?
3. It is a hassle to compile and maintain a complete list of your assets. Sometimes it is even impossible, e.g. with Google Fonts where only the location of the CSS is known, but the location of the font itself varies dependent on the browser and is matter to change.

Alternatively, I could cache assets as they are requested for the first time, which would eliminate the issues above. But that way there is obviously no guarantee that the cache has been populated by the time the user goes offline. Potentially this could be mitigated by registering the Service Worker through the `Link` header, to have it likely running by the time assets are requested. Of course this only works for single page apps, where all assets are requested on every page view.

Or is there any better practice?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using a tool like [Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/) (which I work on) or [`offline-plugin`](https://github.com/NekR/offline-plugin) to automatically generate a list of assets to precache.

I'd also recommend following [these best practices](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/registration) around service worker registration, which defers registration until after your page has loaded its initial content.

At that point, you can tell your service worker to honor the HTTP cache for assets that never change (in workbox, this is done using the `dontCacheBustUrlsMatching` [configuration parameter](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-build#.Configuration)), and you won't end up re-downloading those assets. Some assets can't be safely read from the HTTP cache, like most HTML documents, and those will end up downloaded twice.

Comment: Sure, I could rely on the `Cache-Control` HTTP header to avoid re-downloading assets. But I was wondering whether this really is the best practice. In my case (single page app) I could even setup the server to cache the HTML for a bit, but for most other websites this wouldn't work. Also I still don't see how to go about the Google Fonts issue. Even if I pre-fetch everything else, I still would have to make sure the Service Worker is running by the time the font is downloaded in order to cache it on the fly.

Comment: After the first visit, "unpredictable" URLs like those needed for Google Fonts can be picked up via runtime caching. See also https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/368 for a potential way to address this during the first visit.

Comment: Thank you for the Workbox recommendation! I was able to really improve my service worker by using it.